# How to mount a single non config file in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment which requires to read a license file from a host. The license file is a text file (not a yaml config). I know we can mount a ConfigMap in a deployment but afaik ConfigMap is only in yaml format.

What is the best way to mount this single file into a deployment?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a configmap from any file:

```
kubectl create configmap <map-name> --from-file=file.cfg
```

Then you can mount the configmap to your pod:

```
volumes:
  - name: config
    configMap:
      name: mapName
```

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: config
    mountPath: /dir/file.cfg
    subPath: file.cfg
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the file.cfg need to be a yaml file?

Comment: No. You can use any file.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried but /dir/file.cfg is a directory instead. Did I miss something?

Comment: Make sure the volumes configmap refers to the configmap you created correctly. The configmap should have a key that is the name of the file you constructed it from, above it is "file.cfg". Make sure you use that key name in subPath.

Comment: You can also mount the configmap to a directory without using subPath. Here's more info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap